# Target the next ID inside the Loop (WP)

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is it possible to target the next section inside the loop? so that it will scroll down to the next section area.

Here is my code:

```
<section id ="<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="subpage-wrapper fullscreen background parallax" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')" data-img-width="1400" data-img-height="717" data-diff="100" data-oriz-pos="100%">

<a href="#<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="btn-scroll" data-scroll></a>
</section>
```

Remember that this is inside the WP_Query Loop

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not keeping any selections within your displaying of posts in mind, but I figure you can get 'round by using get_next_post(). Something like:

```
global $post;
$post = get_post($post_id);

$next = get_next_post();
$next_id = $next->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using your own counter?

```
$nextAnchorId = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) { //the loop
    $nextAnchorId++; //make this actually be a reference to the *next* post
    the_post();

    if ($nextAnchorId < $post_count) //don't link to the next post if it's the last one
    {
        echo "<a href='#post-$nextAnchorId'>next post</a>";
    }
}
```